# Display Magento's Register form in a phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, template, register

I want to display Registration form `[ /default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml ]` in my custom template. I have used

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setBlockId('customer_form_register')->toHtml(); ?>
```

this code, but I am not getting the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setBlockId('customer_form_register')->toHtml();
```

Using the above code, Registration form not showing because you are using `setBlockId` instead of `setTemplate` and you need to use form template path. Need to use code like below:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setTemplate('customer/form/register.phtml')->toHtml();
```

If you have custom module created, you can also add block in related handle as below:

```
<block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
    </block>
</block>
```

and call into your custom template like:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register');
```